# Get html of text selection

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, formatting

I am having trouble understanding the code (I am new to JS) and most codes don't work for me. I am building a Chrome Extension to display text selection on a webpage inside a popup. But the text selection does not display in console.
Moreover, I need to preserve formatting of the selected text and display it inside popup.html.

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="para">Some text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload=getSelectionHtml;
function getSelectionHtml() {
var html = "";
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        html = container.innerHTML;
    }
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
}

console.log(html);

return html;
}
```

I tried setting up a breakpoint on the second if statement but even after I  select text the value sel.rangeCount did not change (it remains zero) and the if clause does not execute.

**Similar answers on Stackoverflow**

[Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935320/uncaught-indexsizeerror-failed-to-execute-getrangeat-on-selection-0-is-not)

[Chrome doesn't get the selected html string wrapping tags (contenteditable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691196/chrome-doesnt-get-the-selected-html-string-wrapping-tags-contenteditable)

[Get page selection including HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461989/get-page-selection-including-html)

[Select text in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript)

[Determine which DOM elements the current text selection contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529304/determine-which-dom-elements-the-current-text-selection-contains)

[Get elements in text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202404/get-elements-in-text-selection)

[How to copy formatting from the selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055102/how-to-copy-formatting-from-the-selected-text)

**This code was taken from**

[Chrome doesn't get the selected html string wrapping tags (contenteditable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691196/chrome-doesnt-get-the-selected-html-string-wrapping-tags-contenteditable)

**I almost forgot!**

Intuitively, I think what I am looking for might already have been answered here (quoted above). I tried this too, and downloaded the chrome-extension uploaded by Arne Roomann-Kurrik and it did not help.

[Get page selection including HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461989/get-page-selection-including-html)

Comment: Start with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14351458/1507998

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a chrome extension which takes highlighted text on the page and inserts it into a textarea in popup.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349263/creating-a-chrome-extension-which-takes-highlighted-text-on-the-page-and-inserts)